# Tor Browser is not working in the new Tails 3.3 version

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, linux, browsers

The browser simple doesn't load. When I click in the icon both in the favorites or Internet menu nothing happens. When I try using the command line (through tor-browser command) it shows this:

[image: (pic showing the error)]

The time is adjusted and everything seems OK (I can use the Electrum wallet or torify/torsocks in the command line) only Tor Browser is not working.

If it helps, my CPU is the core I3 (64 bits) and I'm running Tails over a pendrive.

Can anyone help me, please! Thank you a lot!

EDIT: Additional informations:

. I used other browsers with torsocks/torify to test. Those browsers are working! But I don't thing this is safe (If it's safe please let me know).

. I tried to install the Tor Browser directly (downloading from [here](https://www.torproject.org/)) but in this case it's not working! The browser not install. The sandbox not works either.

Comment: Tor Browser itself is crashing, "Segmentation Fault" indicates that some kind of memory access violation has occured. My Tails 3.3 works for me across multiple devices. Assuming that you properly followed the Tails installation instruction, you might want to try an "upgrade by cloning" either from another Tails 3.3 instance or the .iso file with Tails Installer, ensuring that the file passes signature verification. If that still doesn't work then you should try using Whisperback to report the issue to the Tails support team, which should get the appropriate logs to them.

Comment: Also, is there a specific locale or set of steps you're using when starting Tails?

Comment: Thank you for answer me. I actually followed all the demanded instructions. Tails always worked for me pretty well (I use it since the early versions like Tails 0.2 it never gave me any problem) so I'm sure that I installed it properly. I already check it using the sig and by sha256sum. It seems everything good on this point. I installed it two times both with the same problem. I forget to say using other browsers on torsocks works too (I will edit the question).

Comment: Yes, the problem is in `firefox` specifically but I can't reproduce this on my Tails 3.3 install. What method did you use to create your installation?

Comment: I used unetbootin (I'm not sure about it). It's the same method that I always use. Do you think that remove firefox using apt and install it again can make it work? Thank you so much for the attention!

Comment: No, it's not Firefox for the Debian repos. AFAIK unetbootin isn't any of the recommended installation methods. The official installation method is to use [Universal USB Installer](https://tails.boum.org/install/win/usb/index.en.html). It's possible that UNetbootin is breaking something.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [canonizing ironize](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/16144/tor-browser-is-not-working-in-the-new-tails-3-3-version#comment18318_16144). I installed it using [Universal USB method](https://tails.boum.org/install/win/usb/index.en.html) and now everything is working pretty well! (actually ublock isn't but I think this a bug from the distro).

Comment: I can't give points since I'm a begginer

Comment: Yeah, ublock is broken currently, I've proposed a Fix on the Tails bug tracker for this. Hopefully it will be fixed in 3.4.